# Two code different pathways = missmatch

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a code i've to change a bit so it works on another computer it's an INDEX,MATCH formula to get some comments of , anyway here my problem is that even just on my computer if I change the path way ( the closed excel file my code access to find the comments ) i've got a missmatch error on the line ws.Range ...etc and it's driving me crazy if someone knows what the problem is it would save my day.

```
    Sub Thomas()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
    Dim xWb As Workbook

    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    mnt = InputBox("Filename")
    mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\Thomas\[" & mnt & ".xls]Sheet1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("\\data\home\ro\nbi\Documents\Thomas\" & mnt & ".xls")
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    tx = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$G:$G,MATCH(1,(A2=" & mnt2 & "!$A:$A)*(C2=" & mnt2 & "!$C:$C),0))")
    ws.Range("H2:H" & lr).FormulaArray = tx
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    xWb.Close savechanges:=False
    End Sub

So the first one works and this one gives me a missmatch error 


Sub Thomas3()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
Dim xWb As Workbook
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'Z:\Sales\city\Thomas\client\[" & mnt & ".xls]Sheet1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Sales\city\Thomas\client\" & mnt & ".xls")
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
tx = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$G:$G,MATCH(1,(A2=" & mnt2 & "!$A:$A)*(C2=" & mnt2 & "!$C:$C),0))")
ws.Range("H2:H" & lr).FormulaArray = tx
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xWb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: If you step through the code, what is the value of `lr` when you come to `ws.Range("H2:H" & lr)`?

Comment: @Xabier lr = 270

Comment: @Xabier But ?tx in the Immediate pannel gives me the error missmatch

Comment: I've never really worked with Array Formulas, so I'm not 100% sure, but to be honest what you are trying to achieve shouldn't require an Array formula, I don't think... Try adding the following line instead of your ws.Range, `ws.Range("H2:H" & lr).Formula = "=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$G:$G,MATCH(1,(A2=" & mnt2 & "!$A:$A)*(C2=" & mnt2 & "!$C:$C),0))"`

Comment: @Xabier Thanks for the help ! sadly for this formula array formula is necessary or it won't work , if i try to put it like you did just changing `.Formula` to `.FormulaArray` I Get the error Unable to set the FormulaArray of the Range class as array formulas only accept 255 characters